# Salesforce bulk api to create and update 1000 records from a list using java

Tags: java, web-services, salesforce

I have been using `SOAP`API earlier to create and update records from a remote system to salesforce. Then I added an additional functionality of `oAuth 2.0` in my application. But on making connection with this `oAuth`, `SOAP`'s upsert or any other query method refused to accept the connection made by it. Then I tried to switch it to `Rest` API.

Again there is an issue since one can send record one by one in `REST`. Last option for me is `Bulk`API. But I could not find any sample example to create or update a record using a list. Everywhere this `Bulk` API is used with csv file. But I need to pass record from a list of objects as it is done with `SOAP`.

Can anyone provide me some sample example or if this can only be done with csv file then, is there any alternative to use same approach for list?

Comment: You can use OAuth fine with the soap api, take the access token generated from oauth and use it as the sessionId in the soap requests.

Answer (score 1):

If you looking for code examples of data upload with Bulk API, you can find it in Salesforce Developer documentation, for instance - [Walk Through the Sample Code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_code_walkthrough.htm). There is example of uploading data from CSV file.

Also I recommend you to read [Bulk API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_intro.htm) and specially to consider [Bulk API Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_concepts_limits.htm) for better understanding how it is suitable for your case.

**UPD:** [Here](https://github.com/lfreeland/Salesforce-Bulk-API-Starter) is repo with an example of using Salesforce Bulk API from C#.

Comment: Can you provide sample code for salesforce bulk api using C# ?

Comment: Thanks. How can I add the reference SFEnterprise? Do you have any idea of the url used for this ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not familiar with С#, so it will be better to ask someone more skillful in it:)